# How to burn Ubuntu iso from android phone onto microsd?

Tags: micro-sd

I have a laptop that currently has no OS. And the DVD drive isn't working. I already managed to download the Ubuntu iso on my Samsung j3 phone. Question is: is there an app that operates like pendrive, allowing me to burn onto a microsd card? Something that doesn't require rooting and/or OTG?

Thank you,

Jeremy.